# Getting SDL Renderer to work on IOS?

Tags: ios, sdl-2

I've been able to get SDL 2 running on ios but now I can't figure out how to render to ios using SDL functions. I know that you can use opengl, and if all else fails will, but I don't want to because of how much a pain opengl would be for just a 2D game.

My end question is how can you get the SDL Renderer to render on ios?

Comment: It should work out of the box. We need more details to help you though.. What exactly isn't working? Are you able to build the application? What is the output of `SDL_GetError()`?

Comment: @olevegard I'm not able to get a output from SDL_GetError() it seems now the problem is with SDL_Init

Comment: If `SDL_Init` fails, it will return anything else than `0`. Handle that with an `if` and print `SDL_GetError()` to the terminal.

Comment: @olevegard The program gets past the check but fails at "CHECK_WINDOW_MAGIC(window, NULL);" in SDL_Video.c also I guess should note all I'm initiating is SDL_Video -Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ahhh... I've stumbled onto the WINDOW_MAGIC thing before. I think it's UB-related but I'm not entirely sure. My top tip is to make sure you are running the latest version of SDL and all its dependencies

Comment: @olevegard figured it out! Found out I was initializing my SDL_Renderer twice!